# Search with "MATCH AGAINST" causes CakePHP app to crash

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have two projects (A and B).
They're both built on CakePHP framework, and basically, they got the same structure, meaning that both their databases have the same structure. Let's say they are identical.

I have created a view, where I've put all the data needed to perform a search and I called it search_areas. Every column from the tables that are in the view are FULLTEXT indexes.

Now, when I perform a search on Project A, it works like a charm. But when I do it on project B, it takes forever. Actually, something jams, something in the code. The database works fine but the app is unusable for about 10 minutes. Has anybody encountered such a problem?

This is the sql that runs when a search is performed:

```
SELECT 
    Product.*, 
    MainImage.*, 
    Currency.rate, 
    Category.green_tax, 
    CategoriesCategory.full_alias, 
    (Product.price*Currency.rate + Category.green_tax)*1.24 as real_price, 
    MATCH (SearchArea.Cname,SearchArea.Mname,SearchArea.Pname,SearchArea.description,SearchArea.special_description,SearchArea.model,SearchArea.part_number,SearchArea.series,SearchArea.color,SearchArea.big_string) AGAINST ('+search term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score 
FROM `products` AS `Product` 
LEFT JOIN currencies AS `Currency` ON (`Product`.`currency` = `Currency`.`code`) 
LEFT JOIN categories AS `Category` ON (`Product`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN manufacturers AS `Manufacturer` ON (`Product`.`manufacturer_id` = `Manufacturer`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN categories_categories AS `CategoriesCategory` ON (`Product`.`category_id` = `CategoriesCategory`.`category_id`) 
LEFT JOIN search_areas AS `SearchArea` ON (`SearchArea`.`id` = `Product`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `product_images` AS `MainImage` ON (`MainImage`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id` AND `MainImage`.`main` = 1) 
WHERE 
    MATCH (`SearchArea`.`Cname`,`SearchArea`.`Mname`,`SearchArea`.`Pname`,`SearchArea`.`description`,`SearchArea`.`special_description`,`SearchArea`.`model`,`SearchArea`.`part_number`,`SearchArea`.`series`,`SearchArea`.`color`,`SearchArea`.`big_string`) AGAINST ('+search term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND `Product`.`active` = 1 
LIMIT 15
```

Any ideas?

```
****** EDIT *****
```

I ran the query in mysql and it seems that there's the problem. It takes a very long time (2-5 minutes). Seems that I have to optimize my query, maybe find another solution. Thanks for helping. If anybody has an idea how to use the MATCH ... AGAINST ... syntax efficiently on a view or some concatenated element please post. I will probably abandon the above solution.

Comment: How do you determine it's the app's fault, not the queries? Have you run a debugger to determine where it's "jamming"? What's the code that executes this query?

Comment: I ran the query in mysql and it seems that there's the problem. It takes a very long time (2-5 minutes). Seems that I have to optimize my query, maybe find another solution. Thanks for helping. If anybody has an idea how to use the MATCH ... AGAINST ... syntax efficiently on a view or some concatenated element please post. I will probably abandon the above solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing the filterings on a joined table 'SearchArea', no wonder it takes so long.

What your query does is, get all Products, join all the tables and then only keep what matches your filter. Your query should do the following, search SearchArea that have what your looking for and then only join the tables.

You should rewrite your query like so:

```
SELECT 
    Product.*, 
    MainImage.*, 
    Currency.rate, 
    Category.green_tax, 
    CategoriesCategory.full_alias, 
    (Product.price*Currency.rate + Category.green_tax)*1.24 as real_price, 
    MATCH (SearchArea.Cname,SearchArea.Mname,SearchArea.Pname,SearchArea.description,SearchArea.special_description,SearchArea.model,SearchArea.part_number,SearchArea.series,SearchArea.color,SearchArea.big_string) AGAINST ('+search term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score 

FROM search_areas AS `SearchArea` 
LEFT JOIN `products` AS `Product` ON (`SearchArea`.`id` = `Product`.`id`) 

LEFT JOIN currencies AS `Currency` ON (`Product`.`currency` = `Currency`.`code`) 
LEFT JOIN categories AS `Category` ON (`Product`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN manufacturers AS `Manufacturer` ON (`Product`.`manufacturer_id` = `Manufacturer`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN categories_categories AS `CategoriesCategory` ON (`Product`.`category_id` = `CategoriesCategory`.`category_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `product_images` AS `MainImage` ON (`MainImage`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id` AND `MainImage`.`main` = 1) 
WHERE 
    MATCH (`SearchArea`.`Cname`,`SearchArea`.`Mname`,`SearchArea`.`Pname`,`SearchArea`.`description`,`SearchArea`.`special_description`,`SearchArea`.`model`,`SearchArea`.`part_number`,`SearchArea`.`series`,`SearchArea`.`color`,`SearchArea`.`big_string`) AGAINST ('+search term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND `Product`.`active` = 1 
LIMIT 15
```